# PDF page labels created in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC not compatible with Apple Preview?

Tags: macos, pdf, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader, preview.app

**Context**

The first 8 pages of my scanned book are Cover, blank, Title, Copyright, ..., and Table of Contents pages. Then start the pages with the actual pagination printed at the bottom (1, 2, 3,...).

So in order to get the page numbers aligned, I set the page labels of the first 8 pages to roman numerals i to viii. Then the rest of the pages automatically start from 1.

I especially do this because creating bookmarks to the ton of chapters in the book is easier this way (as the page numbers are aligned, I can simply follow the information in the Table of Contents page to quickly create bookmarks).

FYI, this is how I renumber the pages: http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2415896&seqNum=4

**Problem**

Once I export the PDF (with re-organized pages & bookmarks), as I am on Mac, I use the default tool to view my PDF documents, i.e. Apple Preview.

Problem is, for PDFs with re-numbered/re-organized pages, when I click the bookmarks Preview takes me half-way to the relevant page. As in, this:

[image: PDF with re-numbered Pages]
<sup>*(Part of) Table of Contents* page being shown when its respective bookmark is clicked.</sup>

This happens *sometimes* with PDFs with untouched page organization (i.e. no custom page labels defined), and never with PDF ebooks that I purchased, ever!

So I am pretty sure something can be done to fix this in my PDF. I just don't know what setting in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC can help me fix this. What am I missing?

***NOTE:*** For those interested, I made a sample PDF (temporarily) available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5d2for82o9wkmwk/PDF%20with%20re-numbered%20pages.pdf?dl=1).

**Suggested Fix**

Go to Preview > Preferences > PDF (tab) > check "Use logical page numbers". But that's already checked in my case and the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, I always zoom back to 100% view when creating/editing my PDF documents. It so happens that if the PDF's zoom is NOT set to 'Fit to window width' when creating bookmarks in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC (for the rest of the time you can have it anyway you want) that behavior I mentioned in my question happens in Apple Preview (on macOS). Everything works fine if I set the document to 'Fit to window width' before I begin creating bookmarks.

I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC (v2018.009.20050), and have absolutely no idea why this is happening, and if it's a bug.

**NOTE:** Posted this on Adobe Community forums for their staff to see: https://forums.adobe.com/message/10177412 (Well, got nothing but Apple-bashing in return, instead of them addressing the issue. )